# How to apply a filter in a calculated field?

Tags: sql, filter, tableau-api

I am trying to make a calculated field that would show the number of uploads. Our SQL programmer wrote this for me, as he doesn't know Tableau's syntax:

```
select cast([date] as DATE) as [date], count(1) as number into #uploads
from files f with(nolock)
inner join files fr with(nolock) on fr.idl=f.id
where f.[id_user_from] is null and f.[id_file_from] is null
group by cast([date] as DATE)

select * from #uploads
order by [date]
```

This shows number of uploads grouped by date. What I would love to do is create a calculated field, which would display the same result, as applying filters and using CNT(date) to display number of uploads.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally made it.

This is the correct syntax for a Calculated Field:

```
IF ISNULL([id_file_from])
AND ISNULL([id_user_from])
THEN [date]
ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: FWIW, You can leave of the "ELSE NULL" if you prefer. If a calculated field doesn't handle a case, then the calculated field evaluates to null. Also you don't use all caps for keywords and function names, and the square brackets only seem to be needed when field names have spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the additional tips :)